# How to Create Custom Archive page

Tags: archives

I want to create an archive page for  my custom post type.
My custom post type name is spanish so i have created a page archive-spanish.php
but this archive page is not working. default archive showing instead of archive-spansish.php.

Answer (score 1):

Can not help you without reviewing your code. Make sure you have created a proper `page template`.  Go through this [tutorial](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-an-archives-page-in-wordpress/) if you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Thanks for comment . I am following https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates                this

Comment: when i do this and resave  permalink then internal page giving error not found

Comment: Do your front page is working ? have you developed your own theme ? Try to make permalink as plain on id base and then again save it for post type.

Comment: Yes front page is working. I have developed my own theme, I changed permalink as plain then page is working but archive-spanish.php which i have created is not working.